# Unable to subscribe using group by

Tags: java, rx-java2

I have tried many examples but it just didn't work out for me, I simply want to receive the grouped results as list using the following code:

```
  private final PublishSubject<MyObject> s;

  public RabbitMQConsumer() {
    s = PublishSubject.create();
    s.groupBy(x -> x.getName())
    .flatMapSingle(x -> x.toList())
    .subscribe(x -> System.out.println(x));
  }
```

This should work as the example says, however it never prints out anything. If I remove `groupby` it starts to print out the incoming values.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: `toList()` operator waits for the source stream to complete before it returns anything. You might want to use some other operator depends on your use case.

Comment: You need finite groups for `toList`. Do you call `s.onComplete()`?

Comment: @akarnokd no, not sure how I should use that since there is no real completion

Comment: How would you know if a group contains all items then? Does `s` stop sending items eventually? Is there something about the items that can tell if one group is finished and a new group can start?

Comment: I would like to buffer the items actually as in `buffer(24,1)` for a 24 a hour sliding window so thats how we can know if grouping has ended if that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a sample code for your code and works fine

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("AN", "BL", "CL", "DO", "AK", "LL", "BO", "DL");
Observable.fromIterable(list).groupBy(x -> x.charAt(0))
        .flatMapSingle(x -> x.toList())
        .subscribe(x -> System.out.println(x));
```

Output as follow:

```
[AN, AK]
[BL, BO]
[CL]
[DO, DL]
[LL]
```

Why not override onError() to see if there's an error occurs